# Customizing PowerShell tab expansion for domain names

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I often have to type one of our companys domain names in powershell commands - for example when specifying a computer as an argument (*ping machine.domain.com*). I would like to use PowerShell TabExpansion to complete the domain names.

These sources gave me some ideas. But how exactly do I need to modify that function?

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2006/04/26/584551.aspx
http://www.powertheshell.com/dynamicargumentcompletion/

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a module (available here: https://github.com/lzybkr/TabExpansionPlusPlus) to make this easy.  It includes many examples and good documentation.